# pl/sql create function for adding specific column according to a condition

Tags: sql, plsqldeveloper

my table looks like

```
startday endday day1 day2 day3 day4
1        4      2    3    5    3      
3        4      3    5    1    6    
2        3      3    7   10    9
```

input for the function should be startday and endday.

if input is 1 and 3, output should be `day1+day2+day3`

if input is 2 and 3, output should be `day2+day3`

can anyone help me with this...

Comment: can you share the code which you have tried, so that it will be easy to give a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why you should to use function? This may do with simple query:

```
SELECT CASE
     WHEN startday = 1 AND endday = 3 THEN
       day1 + day2 + day3
     WHEN startday = 2 AND endday = 3 THEN
       day2 + day3
   END as result
FROM table1
WHERE startday = YOUR_PARAM and endday = YOUR_PARAM
```

Function would is work if you `startday` and `endday` is unique. Then may write the function so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION func(
  i_startday  INTEGER
, i_endday    INTEGER)
RETURN INTEGER
IS
  l_result INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT CASE
         WHEN startday = 1 AND endday = 3 THEN
           day1 + day2 + day3
         WHEN startday = 2 AND endday = 3 THEN
           day2 + day3
       END
  INTO l_result
  FROM table1
  WHERE startday = i_startday
    AND endday = i_endday
    AND ROWNUM = 1; -- rownum = 1 because I don't know unique of fields

  RETURN l_result;
END;
```

Comment: Now how can we use CASE

Comment: If you have more days, then i think it is wrong model. Why not make a single column 'day' and many rows? It will more normalize than your model. But I don't know youк requirements...

Comment: Let say, communication(phone call) between two. I want to know day-wise duration. That's why I'm having day 1....day 31